# Service generated content interaction with PHP

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, daemon, user-permissions

I have a *daemonized* service that generates content at `/usr/share/service/content`

I need this content to be accessible from PHP.

The service runs under a user named `_service` which belongs to the same group as the one running PHP (`www-data`). Both **service** and **content** directories are owned by `www-data`, and has group write permissions enabled, which I assumed it should suffice.

The service's content is being generated but not stored/written in/to **content**.

If I make the service to run under the `www-data` user it does write the content, and it's accessible from PHP.

What part of my assumption is wrong?

Also, what are the implications of having a folder outside `/srv/...` being accessible to the `www-data` user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start troubleshooting with:

```
su - _service
ls -la /usr/share/service        # test rx permissions on the parent
echo > /usr/share/service/content/delete_me
cd /usr/share/service/content    # test x permission
rm delete_me
env
exit

su - www-data
env
exit
```

More advanced:

su - _service -c "strace /my/path/to/service  -options -options"

Comment: ok, _service `cannot create /content/delete_me: Directory nonexistent` but can `cd` into *content* and `rm` existent files in that directory. Also, it can `nano eraseme.txt` and will create the file.

Comment: su - _service "ls -la /usr/share/service"      # test rx permissions on the parent

Comment: Done, output: `-su: Can't open ls -la /usr/share/service`